# Ruby on rails, inserting information into table from another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, console

I have "vehicles" table which looks like this

> **ID   |   MAKE   |    MODEL**
>
> 1   |   acura  |  cl
>
> 2   |   acura   |  el
>
> 3   |   acura  |  integra
>
> 4   |   audi    |   a3
>
> ... |  ...   |  ...

and I need to make two tables from it, "makes" table, taking only "make" columns information from "vehicles" table and putting it into "make_name" column, which I successfully created by myself(also made it to not repeat itself by uniq method).

> **id  |  make_name**
>
> 1    |  acura
>
> 2 |  audi
>
> 3  | bmw
>
> ... | ...

And second table("make_models") which I already made, but have problems getting needed information into it. Table looks like this

> **id  |  make_id  |  model_name**
>
> id  |  makes id to which current model belongs  |  model from vehicles table

I tried to insert this lines to rails console

```
@vehicles = Vehicle.all
@makes = Make.all
@vehicles.each do |v|
    MakeModel.create :make_id => @current_make = @makes.where(:make_name => v.make).id, :model_name => v.model
end
```

But got this error message

> NoMethodError:   Make Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "makes".* FROM "makes" WHERE "makes"."make_name" = ?  [["make_name", "ACURA"]]
>   undefined method `id' for #

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
MakeModel.create :make_id => @current_make = @makes.where(:make_name => v.make).first.id, :model_name => v.model
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are tying to call `id` on a collection of records here:

```
@makes.where(:make_name => v.make).id
```

If you want to find the first record by make_name, use `find_by` instead:

```
@makes.find_by(:make_name => v.make).id
```

Comment: You could also do @makes.where(...).first.id

Comment: Thank you for your response! :)